# Is this a correct rewrite of this formula?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

The original and final formula are logically equivilant. Are the steps I took to get this logical equivalence valid?

Starting with this formula:

$ (\neg P \wedge \neg Q \wedge R) \vee (\neg P \wedge Q \wedge \neg R) \vee (\neg P \wedge Q \wedge R) \vee (P \wedge Q \wedge \neg R)$

Step 1 - Using commutativity:

$ \equiv (\neg P \wedge \neg Q \wedge R) \vee (\neg P \wedge Q \wedge R) \vee (\neg P \wedge Q \wedge \neg R) \vee  (P \wedge Q \wedge \neg R)$

Step 2 - Using distributivity:

$ \equiv ((\neg P \wedge R) \wedge (\neg Q \vee Q)) \vee ((Q \wedge \neg R) \wedge (\neg P \vee P))$

Step 3 - Using commutativity:

$ \equiv ((\neg P \wedge R) \wedge \color{red}{(Q \vee \neg Q)}) \vee ((Q \wedge \neg R) \wedge \color{red}{(P \vee \neg P)})$

Step 4 - Using the excluded middle:

$ \equiv ((\neg P \wedge R) \wedge \color{red}{true}) \vee ((Q \wedge \neg R) \wedge \color{red}{true})$

Step 5 - Removing (^ true):

$ \equiv (\neg P \wedge R) \vee (Q \wedge \neg R) $

Comment: It looks like step 2 needs association and commutation also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is valid.

I'd commute and associate a little differently, but...that's just presentation.

$\begin{array}{cl}\sf (\neg P \wedge \neg Q \wedge R) \vee (\neg P \wedge Q \wedge \neg R) \vee (\neg P \wedge Q \wedge R) \vee (P \wedge Q \wedge \neg R)
\\[1ex] \sf
((\neg P \wedge R)\wedge \neg Q ) \vee ((Q \wedge \neg R)\wedge\neg P) \vee ((\neg P \wedge R)\wedge Q ) \vee ((Q \wedge \neg R)\wedge P)&\text{commute and associate}
\\[1ex] \sf
(((\neg P  \wedge R) \wedge Q) \vee ((\neg P  \wedge R)\wedge\neg Q )) \vee (((Q \wedge \neg R)\wedge P)  \vee ((Q \wedge \neg R)\wedge\neg P))&\text{commute and associate}
\\[1ex] \sf
((\neg P  \wedge R) \wedge (Q \vee\neg Q )) \vee ((Q \wedge \neg R)\wedge(P \vee\neg  P))&\text{distribute (out)}
\\[1ex] \sf
((\neg P  \wedge R) \wedge \top) \vee  ((Q \wedge \neg R)\wedge\top)&\text{disjunctive complement}
\\[1ex] \sf
(\neg P  \wedge R )\vee(Q \wedge \neg R)&\text{conjunctive identity}
\end{array}$

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used what I learned from your previous answer to my question to solve the distributivity part: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3802404/is-this-a-correct-application-of-the-distributive-law-to-neg-p-wedge-neg-q